# Editing of features with ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET

Tags: editing, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have programmed several ArcMap AddIns by using C# and ArcObjects the last 10 years. Now there is the idea to migrate all the AddIns to ArcGIS Pro, to support the 64 bit versions and be prepared for the end of life cycle for ArcGIS Desktop. I started with this great [Getting Started with the ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkwpq6QuK3U) by Rob Burke and had a quick look at the [ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/#topic1.html).

One of our most used issues (using ArcObjects) is the following. By activating an `ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool` the user can draw a rectangle in the map. All features of a defined feature class inside this rectangle are listed in a custom dialog. Double-clicking one feature opens another custom dialog which allows the user to edit all attributes. After pressing the OK button the feature is updated in the geodatabase by using the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor`.

Am I right, that we don’t have that deep access to ArcGIS Pro with the Pro SDK like we have had with ArcObjects to ArcMap?

This would be very disappointing.

Or am I overlooking something in the API how to read and write features?

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to have the need to develop within ArcGIS Pro, all my experience is with ArcObjects in ArcMap.

I would be surprised if you could not delve right down to the row object and alter values.

So a little search on Google threw up [this page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/#topic6813.html) on the API guide, you can see objects `Row` and `RowCursor`. Esri seemed to have moved all their sample code onto GitHub with no links from the official API manual (not particularly smart...) so one has to trudge through vastness of GitHub and this [top level](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/tree/master/Examples/Geodatabase) seems to be offering links into various subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a newer version of Pro (2.3+) you should be able to do what you want.  I would take a look at this [example](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/Map-Exploration/MapToolIdentifyWithDockpane). I would highly recommend that you download or clone the [pro sdk samples](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples).  Once downloaded you can run the sample by following the instructions on the readme (you may also want to download the [sample data](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples/releases)).  Once you get a handle on how they want to you customize ArcGIS Pro, it's pretty powerful.  The learning curve is there but once you get started hopefully you'll find that a lot of the concepts are easier than ArcObjects.